# Wordpress/Woocommerce- Making a Shortcode a Clickable Link

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, shortcode

below is php code that another member posted which allows for a shortcode to be inserted in the short description of every woocommerce product page (code goes into the theme's function.php file). This has worked perfectly for me, but I have one more thing I need to achieve. I assume this is simple but I have primitive knowledge of php:

How do I make the inserted shortcode into a clickable link that links to a url of my choosing? Below is the code the is currently working and needs a hyperlink:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_form', 'enfold_customization_extra_product_content', 15 ); function enfold_customization_extra_product_content() {
echo do_shortcode("[wpqr-code]");}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
add_action('woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_form','enfold_customization_extra_product_content', 15); 

function enfold_customization_extra_product_content() {
 echo '<a href="https://www.yourlink.com">'. do_shortcode("[wpqr-code]") . '</a>';
}
```

Comment: Works like a charm. Thanks so much for helping out on this.